# trying to sort multiple columns in excel

Tags: excel, sorting

I am trying to avoid manually sorting data that gets loaded into a report daily. I have tried some things I have found but can't get anything to work. I have about 9 diff tables of data I would like sorted ascdending/descending accordingly. let's say some of the data is in row c2-c16 and the next next is i2-i16, then c23-c30. all I need it to do is sort the data in this columns. the columns do have a header if that matters. how could I achieve this?

Comment: Excel has a built-in sorting function that can sort multiple columns. Does that help?

Comment: can I save that like a rule so it auto sorts them everytime the data is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you update your data, there are several ways. One is using a excel vba macro to apply your sorting criteria. To get the right macro, you can simply use the macro generator. It will create something along this:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Makro
'

'
    Range("A1:C4").Select ' Select everything
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ' Sorting criteria here
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B4") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C4") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ' Start the sorting process
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:C4")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Your next step is to make it work with a variable length of data.

## How to apply the sorting after updating the data?

- If you use a macro to add/update data, simply call the sorting `sub` or `function`.
- If you use an approach where some other app modifies your excel, there are several Events available, where you can call your sorting `sub` (sorry, no example, Visual Basic Editor on my Mac doesn't show them.)

Comment: If the answer satisfies your question, please accept it. Thanks.